# How to create summaries of subgroups based on factors in R

Tags: r, group-summaries

I want to calculate the mean for each numeric variable in the following example. These need to be grouped by each factor associated with "id" and by each factor associated with"status".

```
set.seed(10)
dfex <- 
data.frame(id=c("2","1","1","1","3","2","3"),status=c("hit","miss","miss","hit","miss","miss","miss"),var3=rnorm(7),var4=rnorm(7),var5=rnorm(7),var6=rnorm(7))
```

For the means of "id" groups, the first row of output would be labeled "mean-id-1". Rows labeled "mean-id-2" and "mean-id-3" would follow. For the means of "status" groups, the rows would be labeled "mean-status-miss" and "mean-status-hit". My objective is to generate these means and their row labels programatically.

I've tried many different permutations of apply functions, but each has issues. I've also experimented with the aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With base R the following works for the "id" column:

```
means_id <- aggregate(dfex[,grep("var",names(dfex))],list(dfex$id),mean)
rownames(means_id) <- paste0("mean-id-",means_id$Group.1)
means_id$Group.1 <- NULL
```

Output:

```
                var3       var4       var5       var6
mean-id-1 -0.7182503 -0.2604572 -0.3535823 -1.3530417
mean-id-2  0.2042702 -0.3009548  0.6121843 -1.4364211
mean-id-3 -0.4567655  0.8716131  0.1646053 -0.6229102
```

The same for the "status" column:

```
means_status <- aggregate(dfex[,grep("var",names(dfex))],list(dfex$status),mean)
rownames(means_status) <- paste0("mean-status-",means_status$Group.1)
means_status$Group.1 <- NULL
```

Comment: Insa,your "aggregate" solution seems to be the one that most easily allows me to replace mean with sd, so I like the flexibility. I removed 'grep("var",' from the first line of your code because in my full dataset, the column names don't follow a pattern. In dfex, this results in two columns - "id" and "status" - being populated with NAs, but it's easy enough to remove the columns. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest way to do this will be with `data.table` (for big data sets), although I didn't find a way to present new row names in `data.table` object, thus I converted it back to `data.frame`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfex) # convert `dfex` to a `data.table` object
#setkey(dfex, id) # This is not necessary, only if you want to sort your table by "id" column first
dat1 <- as.data.frame(dfex[,-2, with = F][, lapply(.SD, mean), by = id])
rownames(dat1) <- paste0("mean-id-", as.character(dat1[,"id"]))
dat2 <- as.data.frame(dfex[,-1, with = F][, lapply(.SD, mean), by = status])
rownames(dat2) <- paste0("mean-status-", as.character(dat2[,"status"]))
```

Comment: Thanks David. I'm having trouble understanding how exactly this works. Can you comment on '[,-2, with = F]' and on 'lapply(.SD, mean)'?

Comment: `[,-2, with = F]` is just `data.table` way to reference a column, i.e., it means "remove second column". `lapply(.SD, mean)` means "apply the function `mean` on all the columns". You can manually specify the columns you want to apply the function on using `.SDcols`. See `?data.table` for further explanations. I would recommend using this package in the future for aggregations if you have big data sets

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
do.call(rbind,by(dfex[,-(1:2)], paste("mean-id",dfex[,1],sep="-"), colMeans)) 
              var3       var4       var5       var6
mean-id-1 -0.7383944  0.5005763 -0.4777325  0.6988741
mean-id-2 -0.0316267 -0.1764453  0.1313834  0.6867287
mean-id-3  0.7489377  0.8091953  0.9290247 -0.1263163
```

Create both result as a list:

```
 lapply(c("id","status"), function(x) do.call(rbind,by(dfex[grep("var",names(dfex))], paste("mean-id",dfex[,x],sep="-"), colMeans)))
```

Update:

```
library(matrixStats)
 lapply(c("id","status"), function(x) do.call(rbind,by(dfex[grep("var",names(dfex))], paste("mean-id",dfex[,x],sep="-"), colSds)))
 [[1]]
              var3       var4      var5      var6
 mean-id-1 0.6024318 1.36423044 0.5398717 0.7260939
 mean-id-2 0.2623706 0.08870122 0.1827246 1.0590560
 mean-id-3 1.0625137 0.16381062 1.0760977 0.3524908

[[2]]
                  var3     var4      var5      var6
mean-id-hit  0.4369311 1.036234 0.6622341 0.6506010
mean-id-miss 0.8288436 1.035163 0.7688912 0.6799636
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. Not sure if this belongs in a different post, but is there a way to clone your code to calc sd? I saw in another post that the matrix.Stats package had a function called colSds, but when I ran it I got the following error msg: "Error in UseMethod("colCounts") : 
no applicable method for 'colCounts' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Comment: Hi 'user3614783'.  I couldn't reproduce your error using the same dataset example.  Please check the edited version.