# Display row names in a data.table object

Tags: r, data.table

Reference: While trying to answer [this very basic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198629/how-to-create-summaries-of-subgroups-based-on-factors-in-r/24199211#24199211), I suddenly realized that I wasn't able to display `rownames` in a `data.table` object

Toy example

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(A = letters[1:3])
DT
##    A
## 1: a
## 2: b
## 3: c
row.names(DT) <- 4:6
row.names(DT)
## [1] "4" "5" "6" # seem to work
```

or

```
rownames(DT) <- 7:9
rownames(DT)
## [1] "7" "8" "9" # seems to be ok too
```

But when displaying the data itself, row names remains unchanged

```
DT
##    A
## 1: a
## 2: b
## 3: c
```

I would assume `data.table` ignores unnecessary attributes for efficiency purposes, but `attributes` seem to disagree

```
attributes(DT)
# $names
# [1] "A"
# 
# $row.names
# [1] 7 8 9
# 
# $class
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
# 
# $.internal.selfref
# <pointer: 0x0000000000200788>
```

Comment: It should be pretty easy to modify `data.table:::print.data.table` to print the actual row names. I'd have to do some benchmarking, but I don't think you'd lose to much performance. It's a design decision. Personally, I don't see much use for row names in data.tables. You'd never display all of them if the DT is reasonably large and for every other use it should be preferable to have this information in a column.

Comment: In fact, I suspect data.tables only have a row.names attribute for their data.frame legacy.

Comment: @Roland, I gave a specific example when I needed the row names, so it wasn't some arbitrary discussion, but I see where you going. I wonder why Josh erased his answer...

Comment: data.tables don't have row names, on purpose. Having row names is a bad design choice - simply store the data as an extra column.

Comment: @eddi: Bad design choice. Hmm. Care to expound?

Comment: @asb sure - in terms of what data row names represent they are a subset of what an extra column can represent (as row names for a `data.frame` are only a character vector, while columns can be anything), but in terms of their usability row names are far more restrictive and much harder to use than an extra column (and this last point is amplified by how easy it is to use columns in `data.table`, but is also there in `data.frame`)

Comment: @eddi: Thanks. What I have been thinking of is `pandas` which goes as far as to allow multiple indexing. Do you see the two as different designs?

Comment: @asb not sure what `pandas` multiple indexing does - is it a key with multiple columns (which exists in `data.table`), or multiple keys per data (which doesn't exist in `data.table`)? Either way I don't really see what row names have to do with that.

Comment: In my experience I tend to use the `rownames` of `data.frame`s as an method for row indexing. `data.table`'s key system removes the need to use `rownames`to do this.

Comment: @eddi, I think it will be good if you'll post a detailed answer here for the benefit of further readers and so this question will get out of the "unanswered" queue

Comment: If you are converting a data.frame `DF` with row names, you can use `DT <- data.table(DF, keep.rownames = TRUE)` which will create a column with the row names, named `rn`. Still, the data.table `DT` will not have row names. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is more or less verbatim from comments.

`data.table` doesn't support row names. This is intentional, as row names are a bad design choice, because they are far more cumbersome to use than columns (and especially so in `data.table`, where columns are so much easier to deal with than in `data.frame`) and are only a subset of what kind of data columns can represent (recall that row names in `data.frame` are a character vector only, whereas columns can be anything).

Comment: Looking at `pandas.Index`, I don't feel like excusing `data.table` for not implementing a good Index class.

Comment: The data.table team agrees with you. Which is why data.table has such powerful indexing operations, see their introduction/doc: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html.    

row.names might be usable for indexing, but they are not a GOOD index class.