# data table subset using position and name

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I am trying to subset a data table by the numeric values so I can perform a five number summary on the numeric variables only. However, I also need to group the variables. The way that I was trying to do it does not allow me to use the subset and the id variable that is not part of the subset. I know that data table has the `.SD` command, but I cannot seem to get the right combination of apply functions and group in data table. The `id` variable is not numeric and cannot be coerced into being numeric; it is also not unique in my data table.

Here is what I have tried:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

dt <- data.table(num1 = rep(1, 10), 
      num2 = rep(2, 10), 
      num3 = rep(100, 10), 
      id = c("1a", "2b", "2h", "3b", "4b", "5b", "5b", "7n", "8mn", "9y"), 
      char1 = rep("a", 10), 
      char2 = rep("b", 10))

numeric_variables <- 
  lapply(dt, is.numeric) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as.vector()

dt[, numeric_variables, with = FALSE]

dt_summary <- 
  apply(dt[, numeric_variables, with = FALSE][, grep("num", 
                                                 names(dt[, numeric_variables, with = FALSE]), 
                                                                                value = TRUE), 
                                          with = FALSE],  
 2,
 fivenum)  %>% 
 as.data.frame() 

rownames(dt_summary) <- 
  c("Min", "Q1", "Med", "Q3", "Max")

dt_summary

dt[, .(numeric_variables, id), with = FALSE]
```

The final line does not work because `id` is not in the numeric_variables category I created. If someone could direct me to using the correct `by`, `tapply` function with `.SD` I would appreciate it.

NOTE: This is part of a larger program where the user can either select one `id` to look at or compare two `id` variables at once. So, it needs to work for either one or many groups (eventually).

Comment: Your code is not reproducible due to lack of loading required libraries, at first look I see that at least two different packages were used, it is nice to have that in *reproducible* example.

Comment: @jangorecki - thanks; edited.

Comment: `data.table` doesn't support row names, [for good reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24199533/817778)

Answer (score 3):

i guess you are looking for `.SDcols`

```
ind  <- sapply(dt, is.numeric)
(dt_summary <- dt[,lapply(.SD, fivenum), .SDcols = ind])
```

Which gives you

```
   num1 num2 num3
1:    1    2  100
2:    1    2  100
3:    1    2  100
4:    1    2  100
5:    1    2  100
```

As `data.table` does not accept rownames you can do:

```
setDF(dt_summary)
rownames(dt_summary) <- 
  c("Min", "Q1", "Med", "Q3", "Max")

> dt_summary
    num1 num2 num3
Min    1    2  100
Q1     1    2  100
Med    1    2  100
Q3     1    2  100
Max    1    2  100
```

Comment: @dc3 There is really no good reason to use `by` within data.table. If you need grouping, use `data.table`'s  `by` parameter.

Comment: @Roland `dt[, lapply(.SD, FUN = summary), .SDcols = ind, by = id]`