# Failed to bring column values to row names

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I wanted to bring column "Row.Names" to rownames in the following dataset:

```
require(data.table)

CA_Data2 <- fread("Row.Names    Total   Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Sunday
A1  2621    431 444 421 392 272 279 382
A2  1896    275 269 258 287 229 252 326
A3  1660    297 277 239 217 229 169 232
A4  1584    202 233 191 182 311 279 186
A5  1574    253 254 187 245 194 167 274
A6  1400    231 194 181 197 203 195 199
A7  1385    170 161 156 236 226 196 240
A8  1190    213 177 167 175 131 155 172
A9  1256    282 248 202 181 133 99  111
A10 935 128 166 140 133 185 116 67
A11 917 127 137 148 128 140 129 108
A12 834 143 168 115 106 97  82  123
A13 765 156 115 91  118 99  89  97
A14 720 87  100 122 102 111 88  110
A15 727 124 112 106 112 87  88  98
A16 643 95  76  96  95  104 73  104
A17 660 69  115 107 81  101 88  99
A18 625 89  106 107 98  84  79  62
A19 621 106 74  73  130 78  80  80
A20 654 114 107 90  72  43  69  159
A21 570 96  76  116 65  98  60  59
A22 546 120 71  73  80  38  63  101
A23 601 86  94  101 75  51  88  106
A24 787 43  41  58  63  47  49  40
A25 779 62  71  65  51  49  41  45
A26 748 104 53  56  49  59  38  27")
```

I tried this:

```
CA_Data <- CA_Data2[, -1]
row.names(CA_Data) <- CA_Data2[, 1]
```

and got the following error:

> Error in row.names<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value = list(Row.Names =
>   c("A1",  : invalid 'row.names' length

Then I also tried which didn't work:

```
library(tidyverse)
CA_Data <- CA_Data2 %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="Row.Names")
```

I am not sure what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: data.tables do not have a row.name attribute. If you want row.names, convert it to a data.frame using `setDF(ca_Data)`.

Comment: Check the section on `keys`in the [data.table vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html), which will provide you with the information you need. Note that you may use `keep.rownames = TRUE` if really needed in your `as.data.table()`call.

Comment: See also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199533/display-row-names-in-a-data-table-object

Comment: @lmo - thanks for this solution, actually it worked. i didn't know about this conversion in `data.table` package.

Comment: @ManuelBickel - Thanks. This suggestion is really helpful.